# Returning an array from PHP to jQuery from Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get PHP returned array from Ajax.

Here is my Ajax call:

[image]

And my PHP code is this:

[image]

Query is running perfectly.

[image]

I have tried to get values like `alert(data[0].program_title)` in ajax success. But it also returns `Undefined`.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please don't do that, include your code as text in your question not as screenshots

Comment: But to answer your question: `json_encode` your php array and `echo` it in your function to get it in your ajax callback

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't actually output anything since `return` doesn't output the data. You should also return it as json.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your advice. I will do it from the next question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PHP code:

```
//remove
return $data

//change with
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just before flushing the data back to the stream (returning), convert your data (`$data` variable in this case) to JSON string using [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and add the proper [content-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) [`application/json`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/477819/3994502) using [`header`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

However, the best practice is to provide some metadata to your data included in your transfer, like the size of data and count of elements in data and if paginated, which page the data refers to and what the maximum available pages and maximum element size of a page are.

Here's a sample body structure for a more robust data transfer:

```php
$response = [
   'page'          => 0,   // e.g.
   'count'         => count($data),
   'data'          => $data,
   'max_page'      => 3,   // e.g.
   'item_per_page' => 15,  // e.g.
   'status_code'   => 200, // e.g.
];
header ( "Content-Type: application\/json", true , 200);
return json_encode(
   $response
   , JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE
      | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK
      | JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION
      | JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS
      | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES
      | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = [];
if ($numRows>0) {
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}
```

Replace return with echo and add [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
echo json_encode($data);
```